# Deploying a Next.js (Nextra) app into subdirectory

Tags: next.js, subdirectory, nextra

I have a docs website built using [Nextra](https://nextra.site/) (next.js). I am looking to deploy this into `/resources` subdirectory of my website but cannot figure out how. My website is hosted with Framer and DNS is on Route 53. I already configured basepath in Next.js config